# Adding a ClickListener to a TextButton LibGDX

Tags: android, button, menu, libgdx, onclicklistener

I'm developing an app for android but I'm stuck at creating listeners for my buttons. I've already read tons of articles and did testing for several hours now but it just won't work. I did like in this example: https://gist.github.com/mattdesl/5461944 and I even have no errors in my code but my button shows no reaction  at all.

Here is how I tried (or at least one of several tries):

```
...public MainMenuScreen(final Stapler gam) {
    game = gam;

    stage = new Stage();
    table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(table);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Blox.fnt"));
    bodoque = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/bodoque.fnt"));

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

    // Add widgets to the table here.

    TextureRegion upRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture(
            Gdx.files.internal("boxLila.png")));
    TextureRegion downRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture(
            Gdx.files.internal("boxGruen.png")));
    BitmapFont buttonFont = new BitmapFont(
            Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Blox.fnt"), false);

    TextButtonStyle style = new TextButtonStyle();
    style.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(upRegion);
    style.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(downRegion);
    style.font = buttonFont;

    play = new TextButton("Play", style);
    table.add(play);
    play.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y) {
            game.setScreen(game.gameScreen);
            Gdx.app.log("Click", "performed"); // -> never happend
        }
    });

    // add the button with a fixed width
    table.add(play).width(500);
    // then move down a row
    table.row();

}
```

...

I solved or at least found out why its not working. I created an instance of my gamworld with an own InputProcessor and when I don't create that, the listener works.. but now I have to figure out how to use both..

Comment: To use both you can use a InputMultiplexer instead, addProcessor all your processors and then set it on Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer).

Answer (score 3):

You can add a ChangeListener for this. Something like:

```
    play.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            game.setScreen(game.gameScreen);
        }
    });
```

This is the way to listen to button clicks like it is explained in the [libgdx scene2 wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#changeevents).